# Custom protocol handlers in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protocol-handler

Is it possible to register a custom protocol handler in Chrome? This code works in Firefox, but not chrome:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("random",  
                                  "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s",  
                                  "Random Protocal");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/navigator.registerProtocolHandler), it must start with `web+`, starting with Chrome 13.