# Customized protocol handler in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-8, google-chrome-extension, protocol-handler

I would like to open my win 8 app through link in Chrome.
Unfortunately, i can see the link but clicking on it do nothing.

I read about navigator.registerProtocolHandler and made something for me.

[Custom protocol handlers in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374793/custom-protocol-handlers-in-chrome)

I tried what i made in IE and it opens link propely.
In chrome and couldn't do it and the link can't be open?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share an example, how you doing it now that it works in IE? But i don't think it will work in chrome, you might need to use something like http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

Having had this deployed previously, the only way we could get this to reliably work was to use NPAPI plugins, one each for Windows / Mac / Linux. This rapidly became an unmaintainable nightmare. You could also use something like JNLP but this was even worse. We ended up trading off the small UX hit ("Please open our app" rather than "Click to open the app") in favour of a hugely simplified deployment.